# Como mejorar código para eliminar columnas vacías en C#

Tags: c#

tengo este código para eliminar columnas vacías.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = DgvNomina.DataSource as DataTable;

            foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
            {
                for(int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (r[dt.Columns[i]].ToString() == string.Empty)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }
            }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando se ejecuta el código tambien me elimina la columna de ahorro, cuando se supone que solo debería eliminar las columnas de retardo y la de prestamo, esto porque las columnas de retardo y de prestamo estan vacias y la de ahorro no.

Comment: Te falta un else en el caso de que no sea vacía salga del for y siga con la siguiente columna.

Comment: Hola, los datagridview, tienen una propiedad llamada columns la cual te da acceso a todas las columnas del control, a esta propiedad puede acceder a traves del inspector de objetos, una vez que accedas a esta propiedad pues marca la columna deseada y la eliminas y listo, no hace falta codigo

Comment: lo que pasa es que esa tabla la paso a un reporte, entonces recorro la tabla para quitar las columnas vacías, y asi imprimir solo las que tienen datos

Comment: Es que en tu lógica, cuando llega al segundo row, Ahorro está vacía, así que la elimina. Tienes que cambiar el orden: primero columna por columna, y en cuanto una celda tenga datos, salteas esa columna. Al terminar de ver todas las celdas de la columna, si ninguna tuvo datos, recién ahí borras la columna.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De la forma que está implementado tu algoritmo, eliminará cualquier columna que tenga una celda vacía, para que eso no ocurra lo más aconsejable, seria lo siguiente.

```
    DataTable dt = DgvNomina.DataSource as DataTable;
    //Recorremos las columnas
    for (int i = dt.Columns.Count - 1; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        //Declaramos una variable booleana para capturar si la columna está totalmente vacia
        bool iscolumnEmty = true;
        foreach (DataRow r in dt.Rows)
        {
            if (r[i].ToString() != string.Empty)
            {
                //Si al menos una de las celdas de la columna, contiene un valor diferente de vacío, la columna no esta vacía, en cuyo caso no sedebe eliminar
                iscolumnEmty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (iscolumnEmty)
            dt.Columns.RemoveAt(i);
    }
```

Comment: Estás creando un `DataTable` vacío innecesariamente, que en la segunda línea lo descartas. Y además, typo en `Empty`. No probé tu código, pero no estoy seguro que te permita borrar elementos en la lista que estás iterando dentro del `foreach`. Eso creo que Macx lo hizo bien con el `for` inverso. Por lo demás, el concepto creo que está bien.

Comment: @Andrew Tampoco probé mi código,y si estoy seguro que no  permitirá borrar elementos en la lista que estoy iterando dentro del foreach, es evidente ya me pasó tras veces, edito la respuesta de inmediato, gracias por tu comentario.

Comment: Bien, sólo falta `iscolumnEmty` => `isColumnEmpty`. :D

Comment: Excelente, gracias

Comment: @Macx Por nada amigo, estamos aquí para ayudarnos.